# What are the factors that are responsible for our actions?

Tags: karma, sin

What exactly compels us to perform evil or immoral deeds?

What tempts humans to lead hedonistic lives here on Earth?

Comment: Kama (desire), krodha (anger), lobha (greed), moha (delusion), mada (pride), matsarya (attachment) are the root causes of evil as per Bhagavadgita.

Comment: I know :) ... but what is the origin/source of these negative qualities? What causes them to arise in our  psyche? If you say Maya is the cause that gives birth to such qualities, then please define maya as per the scriptures. 

Answer (score 1):

The Q . resembles BG 3.36

> *atha kena prayukto yam* ..*Arjun asked: What exactly impels one to commit sinful acts, even unwillingly, as if by force, O descendent of Vrishni (Krishna)?

BG 3.37 answers the Q.

> The Blessed Lord said This desire, this anger, born of the ality of rajas, is a great devourer, a great sinner. Know this to be the enemy here.(Swami Gambirananda)

`If you say Maya is the cause that gives birth to such qualities, then please define maya as per the scriptures`

The cause can't be something apart from Maya...Scriptures define Maya as Trigunatmika(three modes of nature) detailed in chap. 14

commentary 14.10 Dr. S Radhakrishnan

> All the three modes are present in all human beings, though indifferent degrees. No one is free from them and in each soul one or the other predominates. Men are said to be sãttvika, rajasika or tâmasa according to the mode which prevails .  In the Hindu classification, the psychic characteristics are taken into account. The sāttvika nature aims at light and knowledge: the rājasa nature is restless ness, full of desires for things outward. While the activities
> of sättvika temperament are free, calm and selfless, the rājasa nature wishes to be always active and cannot sit still and its activities are tainted by selfish desires. The tāmasa nature is dull and inert, its mind is dark and confused and its whole life is one continuous submission to environment.

> Though Self is not the agent Rajas makes him act with the idea "Iam the doer" (Anandagiri)

Gita Saadhak Sanjivini , detailed commentary (3.36)
[image]

Gita Saadhak Sanjivini , detailed commentary (3.37)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update**

`Why do you think desire for wordly pleasures is a sinful thing for us humans?` As long as it  conforms with dharma it isn't sinful for a normal person..Yet a lasting impression of the desire, being strengthened ,could  impel one to overlook dharma(eventually), for  its gratification. An aspirant would see the contentment got , to be ephemeral, / any worldly pleasure is always imbibed with a fallacy (dosha darshana).so  revelling in w.pleasure  isnt , *be all and end all* of  their(seekers)  life..

`the devas in swarga-loka can enjoy the company ....`  Experience of tattva-jnana, in human world   is akin to that of a reflection in a mirror, but in swarg , it is as that  of , a reflection in ripples over surface of water.So,  in this regard, a human aspirant has an edge over a Deva ... Although, no sin is accrued (as it is not a material world) , it isn't an everlasting destiny, They may have to return to the human world.
with their strengthened passion for pleasures.

`If  Krishna as a child (as per his lila). ..... Why can't the cosmic laws be the same for all?` ...... Cosmic law is sensitive to erratically varying competencies of jivas..Even amongst humans , intoxication  is a greater sin for brahmana than others . Kshatriyas are prohibited to beg.which does not apply for a brahmana etc.. Animals don't accrue paap for killing . Any justice/law can't be common for all. Lilas in Srimad Bhagavatam are allegories  that illustrate the purport of vedanta. so it shouldn't be **shrunk from that as if something impure., So long as there is selfishness in the heart, understanding  Gopis/Krishna impossible** says Swami Vivekananda (Complete Works)..*Yet some fakester Babas/gurus , of modern times, may enact rasa lila on purpose , for victimizing  women , leaving out other Krishna Leelas.(This happens to be the anticlimax)*

Comment: Why do you think desire for wordly pleasures is a sinful thing for us humans? If the devas in swarga-loka can enjoy the company of beautiful celestials, enjoy the grand luxuries, remain intoxicated with drinks such as soma rasa, and even while engaging in such pleasurable / desire-driven activities, remain completely immune from sin and suffering, then why the same doesn't apply to us humans?

Comment: If Krishna as a child (as per his lila) have a strong desire for butter ... If in his youth (as per his lila) can flirt with gopis and steal their clothes (which infact is a desire driven rajo guna and also an immoral act), then from such actions the Lord never accrues any sin. Why? Because He's above maya. His cosmic laws don't apply to Him but surely applies to us humans and can lead us to the depths of hell ... If He engages in pleasure, then it's lila ... but if we humans do the same, then it's a big sin ... This is purely double standards. I wish the cosmic laws were the same for all.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse *"If He engages in pleasure, then it's lila ... but if we humans do the same, then it's a big sin - This is purely double standards"* - if Ambulance crosses red light, it's allowed, but if I do it, I get fined. This is double standards.

Comment: There is a big difference between Bhagavan's actions and our actions - even if they are exactly same looking. His actions are not borne out of karma, but karuna. Our actions are borne out of karma. He is not bound by the results of his actions. But we are. Btw, who said desire for worldly pleasures is a "sin". Only desire for sinful things is a sin. Virtuous desires are not sins. However, whether virtuous or sinful desire, both bind you in samsara. In that context, one is iron handcuff other is golden handcuff, so both are not freedom.

Comment: Exactly my point. He's above the law just because He's the creator, a special powerful being and since we're not in his league, we'll have to live by whatever whacky laws He set in motion for us.

Comment: Karuna? Sorry but I've to disagree with you. It's Him who creates the jivas and hurls us into this material universe, and if we don't live by His rigid laws we'll have to suffer from diseases on Earth and later in hell. As per Garuda Purana  consuming intoxicants is a huge sin for humans. Molten lava like fluid is shoved down the throats of human souls in hell as per this scripture. And yet look at the devas. They're enjoying the company of damsels and consuming all sorts of intoxicants and still they don't have to suffer neither from diseases, nor in hell. To me, it is surely double standard.

Comment: Truly we are bound by our karma because we crave for the fruits of our deeds, as mentioned in the Gita ... It's our inherent quality as humans and this craving/expecting results of our hard works is what makes us progress in every field. And yet Ishwara made a stupid law (or already it has been in motion since time immemorial) that the more you expect fruits of your deeds, the more you're going to suffer and entangle yourself in the cycle of reincarnation. Such a cruel law to impose upon His own creation. A real compassionate God would never make such absurd laws.